# how to make c-highlight in eclipse?

Tags: java, c, eclipse, android-ndk

I have installed Android NDK and want to make eclipse highlight c-source. How ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll probably want to use the [Eclipse C/C++ Development Tooling (CDT)](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) plugin.

Comment: @Rimidalv then you should accept the answer by clicking the tick mark to the upper left of this answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq